# gitlab feature 'Transfer project' into another namespace moves issues too?

Tags: version-control, gitlab

I would like to use gitlab feature "Transfer Project" to transfer project into another namespace (it can be found in the project settings, under "advanced"). However, I am worried that issues won't be moved along in the new repository under the new namespace.

Can anyone confirm that when I transfer a project to a different namespace also the issues will be moved?

Loosing the issues is not an option for me. I tried also to export them, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/)

> Issues are always associated with a specific project.

and are therefore transfered to the new namespace as are all project related settings. I just tested it with one of my projects.

Comment: I confirm that I moved my project and it worked , the issues moved too. It was easy,